# 1.how to stop run all tests? 2.validation running for about 6 hours in production. how to stop it?

Tags: unit-test, deployment

How to stop run all tests?

I have clicked run all tests in my sandbox and usually gets completed in about 15 minutes. Now its running for about an hour and still not completed?

Note :- Mine is a stage sandbox and now i have written about some 50 more classes and test classes for each of them

is there any way to stop that? Also can I check whats happening behind the scenes and why it is getting delayed?

** Edited ***
Clicked on validate in the changeset that I have uploaded to Production with 700 components..
Its getting validated for the past 6 hours in production and still says in progress.. any ways to stop it???

Comment: Are you sure the tests aren't just still running? If, previously, it took about 15 minutes to run all tests and now, having written several additional tests, wouldn't it make sense for the tests run to take a substantially longer time?

Comment: Yeah I agree.. but initially there were 600 classes, for that it took 15 minutes, now i just added another 50, so i don't think it should take that much time...

Comment: As @JLiljegren__c stated are you sure they were running that whole time?  I have experienced IE9 getting stuck with the validating box on the screen, but the deployment/validation is really completed.  You can log in a different browser while it is validating and navigate to the inbound change sets.  Your change set should be in the table of change sets with something indicating its real status.

Comment: Yearh for sure.. because Other administrator executed it from US, and I was looking at the status from India.. It was saying in progress for about 8 hours... and didnt get completed at all.. Finally I deleted the changeset itself and uploaded new and validated, somehow new changeset validated without any org admin lock. :) not sure if I should mark this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, You cannot stop them. Depending on how your tests were written it may take a long time. If you notice the tests are still running after a long period of time, you may want to contact salesforce support so they can take a look at the process.

Answer (score 23):

Setup->Develop->Apex Test Execution->Select all or Required test classes->Click on "Abort" button.

Comment: @Sathya This is the correct answer.

Comment: This worked.  I had a test suite that with a future method (w/callout) that failed but the test suite never actually terminated.  19 days later, I investigated and found this answer.  Btw...how is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: In Lightning it's Setup > Custom Code > Apex Test Execution or just fast-find Apex T. But my tests that are running way too long in Dev Console don't show up and don't Abort when I click the Abort button. Closing Dev Console and logging out of the org got me a proper "X" on the test once I logged in again and re-opened Dev Console.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cant monitor the Run All Tests you've set off by clicking on the button.
However doing it via the Force.com Migration Tool gives you a process id, which you can query to get the status of the deployment.

However if you run validate only via the IDE, you can see the progress at Setup > Deploy > Monitor Deployments

Comment: If you think your deployment is 'stuck', your best bet is to contact Salesforce Support to try and sort it out.